# Using handler with onCreate() in Android

Tags: java, android, oncreate, android-handler, ui-thread

I initiated Handler for the UI thread inside `onCreate()` method and post new message using this handler.

How android system will handel this code inside `messagequeue`

Is it will be two messages one for `onCreate()` method and another of `runnable` handler
or each line code inside `oncreate()` method will be message inside `messagequeue`

My question because I don't understand how `oncreate()` mehtod work with UI thread `messagequeue`

Comment: Do you have some practical use-case for this? Maybe you have some problem with messages ordering?